# Derivative of SquareRoot with h-formula

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know the general formula for getting a derivative, and the formula for the derivative of the square root function, but I'm interested in how to do prove it using the formula for the definition of the derivative:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x - 3} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x + h - 3}-\sqrt{x-3}}{h}$$

How do I approach this to transform the square root into something which I can
work with?

Comment: Multiply both numerator and denominator of the ratio by the conjugate $\sqrt{x + h - 3} + \sqrt{x - 3}$ of the difference of radicals in the numerator.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Multiply by the conjugate of the numerator $\dfrac{\sqrt{x+h-3}+\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x+h-3}+\sqrt{x-3}}$.

---

> $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{x+h-3}-\sqrt{x-3}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{x+h-3}-\sqrt{x-3}}{h}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x+h-3}+\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x+h-3}+\sqrt{x-3}}=\lim_{h \to0}\frac{x+h-3-x+3}{h(\sqrt{x+h-3}+\sqrt{x-3})}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x+h-3-x+3}{h\sqrt{x+h-3}+h\sqrt{x-3}}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h-3}+\sqrt{x-3}}=\boxed{\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x-3}}}$

Comment: thank you so much 
It's such a simple step but it's not that obvious when you're
not trained with square roots. I just multiplied id with the
same values and then had the squareRoots in the denominator hence had the same problem...

Comment: No problem. Remember that in these kinds of problems, it's often useful to multiply by the conjugate and use the property $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$.